# VBA Word avoid line break when inserting text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following code, which works fine with one exception. The line "MM.Content.InsertAfter Total" inserts the text but also puts in line breaks (e.g. between "topic" and "["), which I do not want. How can I prevent Word from doing that?

```
Sub Schleife_VAR()
    Dim Dok As Word.Document
    Set Dok = ThisDocument
    Dim Tabelle As Table
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Number As Integer

    Dim MM As Word.Document
    Set MM = Documents.Open("C:\Users)

    For Each Tabelle In Dok.Tables
        Number = Dok.Range(0, Tabelle.Range.End).Tables.Count

        counter = Dok.Tables(Number).Rows.Count
        For i = 1 To counter
            Dim j As Integer

            If InStr(1, Tabelle.Cell(i, 1).Range.Text, "TOPIC") Then
                    Dim Topic As String
                    Topic = Tabelle.Cell(i, 2).Range
            ElseIf InStr(1, Tabelle.Cell(i, 1).Range.Text, "VAR") Then
                    Dim Total As String
                    Total = Topic & " " & "[" + Tabelle.Cell(i, 2).Range & "]"

                    MM.Content.InsertAfter Total
            ElseIf InStr(1, Tabelle.Cell(i, 1).Range.Text, "FILTER") Then
                    MM.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Style = MM.Styles("Filter")

                    MM.Content.InsertAfter "Filter: " & Tabelle.Cell(i, 2).Range    
            ElseIf InStr(1, Tabelle.Cell(i, 1).Range.Text, "QUESTION") Then
                  MM.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Style = MM.Styles("Question")

                  MM.Content.InsertAfter Tabelle.Cell(i, 2).Range
            End If
            MM.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Style = MM.Styles("Remark")
        Next
    Next

    Selection.Range.Case = wdTitleSentence

End Sub
```

Comment: Place the cursor on the InsertAfter.  Press F1.  Read the page, especially the second paragraph of Remarks.

Comment: I am sorry but I still do not get it,  The second paragraph says: "You can insert characters such as quotation marks, tab characters, and nonbreaking hyphens by using the Visual Basic Chr function with the InsertAfter method. You can also use the following Visual Basic constants: vbCr , vbLf , vbCrLf and vbTab."

I did that, but still not sure why I does not work

Comment: Off by one error <blush> It was the third paragraph.

Comment: I read the next paragraph aswell. Also I tried the example-code, which did not work. VBA marks an error at ".start" saying that this  method cannot be found. Can you please enlighten me? ;)

Comment: This line of code is incomplete  'Set MM = Documents.Open("C:\Users)'.  If you want people to help then the code you post should be complete.

Comment: Sry but I have never received such a bad help by anyone on SO. And I do not see any value in posting my personal path of my document. Anyways I found a solution. I look up the link and post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a few of the variables used are not declared in the code in the question. That makes trouble-shooting this uncertain.

On the assumption these should be holding String data and not a Word.Range then the issue comes from `Tabelle.Cell(i, 2).Range` An entire cell's content includes the end-of-cell characters ANSI 13 & ANSI 7; ANSI 13 is a paragraph mark - this generates the new line. I use a function to trim a cell's content which can be used as follows.

(Note: When querying the string content of a range in Word it's better to use `Range.Text` and not just `Range`. VBA is very forgiving and uses default properties for objects(such as `Text` for a range), but sometimes it can make mistakes, such as when a variable is not explicitly defined as a `String`.)

```
 Topic = TrimCellText(Tabelle.Cell(i, 2).Range.Text)

Function TrimCellText(r As word.Range) As String
    Dim sLastChar As String
    Dim sCellText As String

    sCellText = r.Text
    sLastChar = Right(sCellText, 1)
    Do While sLastChar = Chr(7) Or sLastChar = Chr(13)
        sCellText = Left(sCellText, Len(sCellText) - 1)
        sLastChar = Right(sCellText, 1)
    Loop
    TrimCellText = sCellText
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

Before complaining you should read the rules for posting in this forum.

Having looked at the code above you are consistently adding text to the end of the document specified by MM because you are referring to the Content property.  For this reason the following paragraph applies.

> However, if the range ends with a paragraph mark that also happens to
>   be the end of the document, Microsoft Word inserts the text before the
>   final paragraph mark rather than creating a new paragraph at the end
>   of the document.

So I feel your pain.  When I try inserting text such as "Hello World" using ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter "Hello World" it works fine.  Thus I can only suggest that the text you are getting from Tabelle has a new line or some other invisible characters embedded at the start of the cell text.  I can't test this as I don't have a copy of your source document.  What do you see when you turn on formatting view? (Click the reverse P on the paragraph tab and look for the cell text starting on the first line in the cell with no obvious 'Zwielichtig' characters in front of the text you actually want.).

Below is your code as I would write it.

Option Explicit

```
Sub Schleife_VAR()
Dim Dok As Word.Document

Dim Tabelle As Table
Dim Cell As Range
'Dim counter As Integer
'Dim i As Integer
'Dim Number As Integer

Dim MM As Word.Document
'Dim j As Integer
Dim my_row                            As Word.Row
Dim my_cell1_text                     As String
Dim my_cell2_text                     As String
Dim Topic As String
Dim Total As String
'Set MM = Documents.Open("C:\Users) where is the rest?

    Set MM = ActiveDocument
    Set Dok = ThisDocument  ' Bad practise.  ThisDocument refers
                            ' to the Document holding the macro code.
                            ' Typically this is the Template on which the
                            ' Document is based. Your usage may be different.
    ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter "Hello World"
    For Each Tabelle In Dok.Tables

        'Number = Dok.Tables.Count

        'counter = Dok.Tables(Number).Rows.Count
        For Each my_row In Tabelle.Range.Rows
        'For i = 1 To counter

            my_cell1_text = my_row.Range.Cells(1).Range.Text
            my_cell2_text = my_row.Range.Cells(2).Range.Text

            Select Case my_cell1_text

                Case "TOPIC"
                    'If InStr(1, Tabelle.Cell(i, 1).Range.Text, "TOPIC") Then
                    ' Topic = Tabelle.Cell(i, 2).Range
                    Topic = my_cell2_text

                Case "VAR"
                    ' ElseIf InStr(1, Tabelle.Cell(i, 1).Range.Text, "VAR") Then
                    ' Total = Topic & " " & "[" + Tabelle.Cell(i, 2).Range & "]"
                    Total = Topic & " [" & my_cell2_text & "]"
                    MM.Content.InsertAfter Total

                Case "Filter"
                    ' ElseIf InStr(1, Tabelle.Cell(i, 1).Range.Text, "FILTER") Then
                    ' MM.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Style = MM.Styles("Filter")
                    ' MM.Content.InsertAfter "Filter: " & Tabelle.Cell(i, 2).Range
                    MM.Content.InsertAfter "Filter: " & my_cell2_text
                    MM.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Style = MM.Styles("Filter")


                Case "QUESTION"
                    ' ElseIf InStr(1, Tabelle.Cell(i, 1).Range.Text, "QUESTION") Then
                    ' MM.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Style = MM.Styles("Question")
                    ' MM.Content.InsertAfter Tabelle.Cell(i, 2).Range
                    MM.Content.InsertAfter my_cell2_text
                    MM.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Style = MM.Styles("Question")

                Case Else

                    ' Do nothing ?

            End Select

            MM.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Style = MM.Styles("Remark")

        Next

    Next

' There is no selection made in this method so I don't know to what the next line is referring.
Selection.Range.Case = wdTitleSentence
End Sub
```

Below is a function that will remove any dodgy characters from a string.  I use it for sanitising filenames.

```
Public Function Sanitise(ByVal this_string As String) As String

    Dim my_regex               As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp

    Set my_regex = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    my_regex.Global = True
    my_regex.MultiLine = True
    my_regex.Pattern = "[^\\\w:\.]"

    Sanitise = my_regex.Replace(this_string, vbNullString)

End Function
```

Which you could use to do

```
my_cell2_text= Sanitise(my_row.Range.Cells(2).Range.Text)
```

to see if that cures your problem.